# Android Studio emulator Firebase (login/register) not working but works on device

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to figure out why suddenly the emulator doesn't recognize the Firebase of the application but it works perfectly fine when I install it on my phone.

I am certain that this is not a code issue cause I just did and reverted the changes BEFORE I had this problem and it still does the same. I think that this is the issue with the emulator itself but I am not entirely sure.

I have done the following:

- Tried different device from AVD
- Already tried any possible combination of the minsdk/compiledsdkversion/targetedSDKversion
- Cold booted the emulator
- Wiped the emulator
- Reinstalled the emulators
- I tried installing NOX but sadly the version of that android is 7 (I need to test the app on higher versions)
- Tried Rebuild project / Clean project
- Updating the google play services on the emulator
- Tried looking the firebase settings on the browser
- Restarting my pc
- Restarting Android Studio
- Updated the firebase version on the dependencies
- And yes, the emulator has an internet connection
- Logcat doesn't show a particular error except for this.

```
E/netmgr: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:network' service: Invalid argument
2022-08-02 06:25:20.186 443-443/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2022-08-02 06:25:21.664 449-449/? E/wifi_forwarder: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:wififorward' service: Invalid argument
2022-08-02 06:25:21.664 449-449/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
```

I don't know if that's relevant but that's the only "error" the log shows (It's the only one that's in red text. and it happens often whenever I test it.)

For those wondering what happened before this, I only changed the minimum SDK and the TARGETED SDK  because it's not working on my phone earlier. After I fixed that then the firebase started not to work (But like I said, as I am typing this post the codes are reverted to the moment BEFORE I changed the minsdk/targetedsdk so I doubt the problem is within the codes but then again, I am not an expert and I am not sure.)

Answer (score 0):

Even I have faced this issue multiple times. From my experience it is an issue with the emulator. So whenever I deal with firebase related features I test it on a real device. Hence I would also recommend you to test it on a real device when it uses firebase.

Comment: People observe this issue is fixed with latest 31.3.12 emulator. But in Android emulator release notes no 31.3.12 is to be found, just the previous version 31.3.11.